# What is the correct way to override a inherited property's default value?

Tags: c#

I have two classes, one inherits from the other and I want to override the default value from the parent class in the child class.

Is this the correct way of doing it?

```
public class Foo 
{
    public virtual string FooValue { get; set; } = "foo default value";
}

public class Bar : Foo 
{
    private string _fooValue = "bar default value";
    public override string FooValue 
    {
        get => _fooValue;
        set => _fooValue = value;
    }
}
```

I have seeing people using `DefaultValue` attribute, but not sure what is the correct way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set it in the constructor of Bar, no need for virtual:

```
public class Bar : Foo 
{
    public Bar() {
        FooValue = "bar default value";
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this override the value if I instantiate and add the properties? e.g. `var bar = new Bar() { FooValue = "some value"}`

Comment: No, the constructor is run first, the object intializer properties are set afterwards.